# [iOS][ReactNative v0.19.0] Custom view has an unexpected black background

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a custom view drawing colored path, worked well before React Native 0.19

But on React Native 0.19, it seems like there is a default black background, which prevent me from using translucent colors.

It looks like this on React Native 0.19:

[image]

If I draw nothing or some translucent color on the entire rect, you'll see the black layer

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [path fill];
}
```

please help me fix this problem.

- React Native v0.19.0
- running on iPhone 6s Plus (9.2) simulator

Comment: remove [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0] setFill];

Comment: no, it doesn't work, it's transparent, notice alpha is 0

Comment: You can use this

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextFillPath(context);
        
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
        [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
        [path fill];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common when you override `-drawRect` to perform custom drawing, you need to set its opaque to NO or set its background colour manually in `-initWithFrame:`

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    [self setOpaque:NO];
    // or [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  }
  return self;
}
```

---

Btw, it's not black though we see it in black. It's just because there's no colour offered there to be shown appropriately, cause you override `-drawRect`, you take charge of the drawing related logic, but you did't take care of this area as expected.

Comment: It works, thanks Kjuly! But I don't understand why it worked before RN 0.19?

Comment: @xinthink as far as i know, it suppose to be same as always, maybe some code changing lead this issue not exposed in ur project?

Comment: Sorry, I meant React Native v0.19.0 for RN. So it should be the React native draw a color for me before the v0.19 version. Thanks @Kjuly

Comment: @xinthink yeah, it might be, not totally sure about it.